# Cypher/Neo4j – Storing bracketed variable in global scope

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following cypher query fails at the last line because `p2` is only defined within scope after `EXISTS`, but is there a way to bring it out of that scope somehow (e.g. set it to a global variable) and return it?

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE EXISTS {
  MATCH (p{name: 'José'})<-[:CHILD_OF]-(p2:Person)
  WHERE p2.name IN ['Roberto', 'Gustavo']  
}
RETURN (p), (p2) // fails
```

**P.S.:** I know that the easiest solution is to just NOT use the scope in the first place, my question is whether the functionality I'm looking for exists.

Answer (score 1):

Existential queries used in `EXISTS` cannot return values. You need to use `CALL` if you want to do post processing of a sub query's results.
It looks like you want to try:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
CALL {
  WITH p
  MATCH (p{name: 'José'})<-[:CHILD_OF]-(p2:Person)
  WHERE p2.name IN ['Roberto', 'Gustavo'] 
  RETURN p2 
}
RETURN p, p2
```

The WITH in the CALL makes the p from the outer query available to the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(p2:Person)
WHERE p.name = 'Josè'
AND p2.name IN ['Roberto', 'Gustavo']
RETURN p,p2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the where exists clause and directly do the query on Jose and his parents.

```
MATCH (p: Person{name: 'José'})<-[:CHILD_OF]-(p2:Person)
WHERE p2.name IN ['Roberto', 'Gustavo']  
RETURN p, p2
```